# How to deal with a large queryset in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I need to process a queryset in Django of about 15 000 rows. I basically loop through the queryset and create a new object from each object in the queryset. The new object contains a number of calculated fields, as shown below. The result of the report is then saved as an Excel file, with one row for every CalcEntry.

```
def get_report(report_date):
    for db_entry in my_large_queryset:
        yield CalcEntry(db_entry, report_date)

class CalcEntry(object):
    def __init__(self, db_entry, report_date):
        self.db_entry = db_entry
        self.report_date = report_date

    @property
    def calc1(self):
        if self.db_entry.value_date > self.report_date
            return self.db_entry.value
        return 0

    @property
    def calc2(self):
        #... There's about 20 of these calcs in the CalcEntry class
```

Creating the report takes about 20s, so I'm close to getting a timeout error since it is running on Heroku (Heroku times out after 30s). However, **just looping through the queryset takes a lot of time**, without even creating the CalcEntry class. I read that looping through large querysets are not recommended, but I thought large would be more than 15 000.

It looks like instead of looping through the queryset, I should use the values() method. Consequently, I thought of the following solutions, but all of them requires a lot of work so I'm hoping there is another better way of dealing with this problem:

1. Try to calculate the fields using F expressions and then use values() on the queryset. This will result in a monster query though.
2. Run the calcs in the background and save it in a new db table at a specific report date. Again in this case I can then use the values() method to get a list of dictionaries that can be used to create the Excel file.
3. Do some sort of raw SQL calc, but I would want to avoid this if possible (I'm using postgreSQL)

How do people generally deal with large querysets and what other alternative to looping over the queryset are available?

Comment: This question is too broad and also primarily opinon based. What you should really do is post your actual code that shows the calculation.

Comment: I don't think more detail to my question would make a difference, since my issue is just looping through a querset of 15000 entries and not even doing anything in the loop takes about 5 seconds. One solution is to use the values() method, but I was wondering if there's other options available.  When using the values() method, there's obviously other disadvantages compared to using a loop

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with the comments that more detail would be helplful.

However, in lieu of that, one thought would be to take those calculations and turn them into model fields.  For example, if the objects you're looping through are a model called Rectangle as in the below:

```
class Rectangle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    side1 = models.IntegerField()
    side2 = models.IntegerField()
```

And you want to spit out a Excel file with the **area** and **perimeter** of each Rectangle, you could add two more fields:

```
area = models.IntegerField()
perimeter = models.IntegerField()
```

And calculate those *as the Rectangles are created* as opposed to what you're doing now where you calculate them as you make an Excel sheet.  For the items you already have you can then update the models for the new fields and then write a script to do a one-time calculation to populate them.

This way you can just call

```
Rectangle.objects.all().values('name', 'area', 'perimeter')
```

to get just what you want.